# Switching HDMI signals without break

Tags: camera, hardware, hdmi

I need to switch between two or three HDMI signals (1080p is sufficient) for a video stream to a beamer. For example, I would like have a presentation coming from a laptop, and one or two cameras and then switch between those devices as fast as possible.

I tested some simple switches from Amazon, but everytime the input signal is changed, the beamer/output devices needs to reconnect to the new device, creating a black screen for a couple of seconds.

Does anyone have a recommendation for a small, rather cheap HDMI switch that comes without that problem?
I have to remark that between the switch and the beamer, there is an HDMI-Extender that takes a few seconds to reconnect after an interrupt, so the output signal of the switch must be consistent.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try it with a device like [that one](https://www.techly.com/5-in-1-out-hdmi-switch-with-remote-control-4kx2k-3d.html). It takes the responsibility on the HDCP-negotiation for you, what should be what you are looking for.

Comment: That specific device also takes a few seconds to switch, but as you stated, it will not disconnect from the beamer in the meanwhile. That looks much better now, thanks!